# A good design to pack parameters?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I have an object that takes plenty of parameters to its constructor (from 9 to 13 depending on use).

I want to avoid the ugliness of `new MyObject(param1, param2, param3 ... param13)`.
My first attempt was to create a `class MyObjectParams` with properties with public getters and setters, it gives something like that :

```
var objectParams = new MyObjectParams
{
    Param1 = ...,
    Param2 = ...,
    ...
};
```

I see some big projects like [SlimDX for their PresentParameters](http://www.google.com/codesearch#jZI2frAhW-g/trunk/source/direct3d9/PresentParameters.h) use this design. It looks better. But the class is not immutable.

I'd like my `MyObjectParams` to be immutable while still using a *clean* construction style. This is how it would look like with an immutable class :

```
var objectParams = new MyObjectParams
(
    param1,
    param2,
    ...
);
```

Note: it's just the long constructor line broken into several, so it's cleaner but still not as readable as initializers.

I was thinking of using named parameters to get both an immutable class and a more or less clean code, but I'm not sure whether this actually *is* a good idea:

```
var objectParams = new MyObjectParams
(
    param1: ...,
    param2: ...,
    ...
);
```

**Should I use named parameters? Can you think of a better approach to solve this problem?**

---

Edited regarding an answer below: unfortunately, I don't really think the design is *bad*. The 9 parameters *really* are required and remain constant throughout the entire life of the object. I cannot provide a default value for them as it is completely usage-dependant.

Comment: I deleted my answer, when I figured that you were actually considering using the "parameter class" approach. Personally, I think that is a solid way to do it. That the MyObjectParameters is not immutable shouldn't matter, as long as the "MyObject" class itself is.

Comment: Do you Need to make it accessible? If Yes, you could add a SetReadOnly() Operation. Once called, every setter would throw. You could set MyObjectParameters "read only" in MyObjects constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into designing a solution in which you wouldn't need this amount of parameters? Having a lot of parameters makes the code very tightly coupled which reduces maintainability. Maybe you can redesign a small amount of code to a design which better separates the responsibilities of the class?

Comment: Of the 13 parameters, 9 *really* are required and must be set at construction. This is the best refactor I could get, so my problem still applies!

Answer (score 2):

I really like the way [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says a few things:

```
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
[...]
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
```

I believe that having a dedicated `Options` class of some kind with the exhaustive list of all possible parameters is a good idea.  Allow your `MyObject` constructor to require an `Options` instance, and then store a reference to the instance as a field on `MyObject` and refer to its getters/setters.  (Storing the reference will be much superior to trying to parse the options and transfer their values to the `MyObject` instance.  Now *that* would be messy.)  With all data access delegated to the `Options` class, you will have successfully encapsulated the object's configuration, and you've designed a simple API for option access as the same time.

If `Options` has no reason to be publicly accessible, make it a private class definition and then you're free to maintain changes to `Options` logic without modifying `MyObject`.  I believe that is a fair solution to you as the developer, and doesn't commit atrocities.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor could have only a small number of parameters, the ones required for proper object initialization. You could then have a number of properties that can be set after the object has been constructed. You can set default values for those properties in the constructor and the client can set the ones he/she requires.

```
class Person
{  
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Address = "Unknown";
        Email = "Unknown";
    }

    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public int Age {get; private set;}

    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
}

Person p = new Person("John Doe", 30);
p.Email = "john.doe@example.org";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the builder pattern to construct an immutable object.

```
public sealed class ComplexObject
{
    public int PropA { get; private set; }
    public string PropB { get; private set; }

    public sealed class Builder
    {
        int _propA;
        string _propB;

        public Builder SetPropA(int propA)
        {
            // validate
            _propA = propA;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder SetPropB(string propB)
        {
            // validate
            _propB = propB;
            return this;
        }

        public CustomObject ToCustomObject()
        {
            return new CustomObject
            {
                PropA = _propA,
                PropB = _propB
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var custom = 
    new CustomObject.Builder()
    .SetPropA(1)
    .SetPropB("Test")
    .ToCustomObject();
```

**Final Thoughts**

Despite my previous suggestion I am in no way against using named parameters if they are available.